# Words split over lines in questions on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just noticed over the last couple of days that questions have words split over lines on the mobile site. I'm pretty sure this didn't happen before. Anyway, it doesn't look right. Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: This is SE-wide: post here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279352/154443 - fix is in train.

Comment: Thanks, Doc! You can tell how much time I spend on the other SE sites. (Not much...) I'm guessing this post might as well be deleted now the problem's fixed, right?

Comment: It's a pity there isn't a sensible way to close as dupe of one on a different site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is completed as per meta.stackexchange.com/q/279352/154443